# How to customize accounts-ui package for MeteorJs

Tags: meteor

I just started an app on **meteor js**. I setup **accounts-ui-bootstrap-3** and got the login system working wonderfully with **twitter** login auth.

I even got the profile pic pulling in very nicely. It all works great.

Now I want to add some options to the dropdown so that users can add additional information to their profile and modify their existing information etc

Does anyone have any ideas how I would do this? I have been looking through the source code but cant seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience there are two ways to do this.

1) Insert the extra options dynamically on load using JQuery by doing something like this:

```
Template.templateName.rendered = function () {
    $('#login-buttons').append(SOMETHING CUSTOM).append('Some other custom thing');
}
```

You can then style it all with CSS and enjoy life.

2) You can go into the accounts-ui pacakge and modify things. That can typically be found at .meteor > local > build > programs > client > packages > accounts-ui. Or you can modify globally by going to .meteor (in the home directory) > packages > accounts-ui > YOUR PROJECT FOLDER. There you'll see all the js files that compile into the build and modify them there.

Good luck!
db